# SF Short Story Identification: "stupidity/apathy tax"?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to remember a short story in *Asimov's* or *Fantasy & Science Fiction* or one of those digest magazines in the late 1990s or early 2000s (when I subscribed -- no later than 2008).

In it, the government imposes a "stupidity tax," and the protagonist calls to challenge it, and it turns out it's an "apathy tax" instead -- it's always waived upon request.

*(Alas, no one is thinking of the Dunning-Kruger effect -- the truly smart may think they aren't, and won't request the waiver, while the bold-yet-stupid will plunge ahead and make the request.  We were so innocent then. sigh.)*

I think that's the whole thing: no dramatic plot or anything else, barely more than a vignette, from what I recall. It might have been a short-short or flash fiction?

I'm pretty sure it was set in the near-future, with just that one tiny change.

I want to know because I semi-refer to "that SF story about an apathy tax" whenever I encourage people to challenge insurance denials: the software seems to be designed to reject most things upon first pass-through, but then (appears to) approve over 2/3 with a single challenge, and 85% with a second one.

I'm just annoyed at my vague citation.

Comment: Sounds like it might have been a candidate for *Analog*’s “Probability One/Zero” column of flash fiction.

Comment: I don't remember that column -- do you know when it ran?  I'm only thinking it was so short because so little actually happened.  It's not like they got a team together to solve this (again, as best as I remember).

Comment: From ISFDb, a listing of all [Probability Zero columns in Analog](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?9857).

Comment: Found it -- DavidW, if you want to make it an official Answer so I can give it the checkmark?  It's called "I don't know and I don't Care" by Shane Tourtellotte, 1998, and it is reprinted here: http://shanetourtellotte.com/IDKAIDC.htm  I want to give you the credit because I wouldn't have browsed ProbZero without your link!

Comment: This reminds me of how I've seen a government-sponsored lottery called "a stupid tax." The idea being that the dumber you are, the more money you *choose* to give to your government in exchange for a stack of (probably useless) lottery tickets, week after week, without learning anything from the experience. In effect, *you decide* how much tax to pay for being stupid.

Comment: Actually, @lorendiac, for people too poor to get a useful bank account, lottery tickets are actually a reasonable way to occasionally cash out into a modest purchase that it would be difficult to save up for otherwise.  (Yeah, I was shocked to see a rational reason, and probably not the biggest factor, but it's there.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placeholder Answer until DavidW posts one.  He suggested
that I look at:

> From ISFDb, a listing of all [Probability Zero columns](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?9857) in Analog. – DavidW 21 hours ago

And then I found that it was **"I don't know and I don't Care"** by Shane Tourtellotte, 1998, and it is reprinted here: http://shanetourtellotte.com/IDKAIDC.htm